# Deriving a parametric parabolic equation given the source and destination coordinates

Tags: java, math

For a program, stars appear at the bottom or top of the screen at a random, precalculated position. The stars travel to their predetermined destination which is the top or bottom of a letter (based on if the star originated above or below the letter). Currently the star' motion are mostly linear, with a bit of curve from some homebrewed equation. I would like a solid parabolic equation in which the stars reach their destination position at an angle that is roughly perpendicular (+- 20 or so degrees) to the top/bottom of the destination letter. I phoned in calc 3 so I can't figure out how to implement the parabola for this problem. I'm also open to a completely different way of animating these objects. Help appreciated. Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Extraneous info: the stars' source position is never directly above or below the letter they are to collide with, and is never more than half the screen's width away for the bottom-originating stars or 1/3 of the screen's width away for the top-originating stars.

Comment: Your question isn't terribly clear. What do you mean by "collide"? When you say "perpendicular to the destination letter", what aspect of that letter do you mean? When you say "concave up", what is that? The simplest way to answer might be to take one of your pictures and just hand-draw an example trajectory on to it.

Comment: Also, when hand-drawing the trajectory, please mark all control values (angles, points, tangent lines, etc)

Comment: Your drawing doesn't have enough control points; two points gives two equations, three unknowns. I tried solving for it with the initial trajectory being an input, but quickly ended up with a fourth-order polynomial mess, so maybe pick some other control point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we want a parabola, with the apex known, as well as some other arbitrary point.

First, consider the apex. At the apex of a parabola, the first derivative of y-position is zero; `d/dx(ax^2 + bx + c) = 2ax + b`, so solving for `x` when `2ax + b = 0` we have `2ax = -b => x = -b/2a`. So `X_a = -b/2a`.

Now, we can use this to solve for either `a` or `b`. So, `a = -b/2X_a`.

We also know the y-coordinate for the apex point: `Y_a = (-b/2X_a)X_a^2 + bX_a + c`; `Y_a = -bX_a/2 + bX_a + c`; `Y_a = bX_a/2 + c`; solving for `c`: `c = Y_a - bX_a/2`.

Now plug this in the equation for the other known point: `y = (-b/2X_2)x^2 + bx + Y_a - bX_a/2`; `y = -bX_a/2 + bx + Y_a - bX_a/2`; `y = -bX_a + bx + Y_a`; solve for b: `bx - bX_a = y - Y_a`; `b(x - X_a) = y - Y_a`; `b = (y - Y_a) / (x - X_a)`.

And now you have formulas for the three parameters of a quadratic function (with `a` and `c` dependent on `b`), so you can easily obtain a parametric form.

Comment: Let there be a parabola w/ source/vertex (h,k), destination point (x,y), and foci [a]. Then y = a * (x-h)^2 + k, for which a =  (y-k)/(x-h)^2. Solve for a, then use the formula y = a * (x-h)^2 + k to find any point along the parabola. To animate the object's movement along the parabola, set x = h initially, and increment x over time.